# Microsoft Web Farm Framework failing due to lack of hard drive space

Tags: windows, iis, web-farm, web-platform-installer

I have Microsoft Web Farm Framework setup in a production environment and it seems to work well (better than keeping the servers in sync manually) except that it is causing an excessive number of log files to be generated.

I just removed 450 GB (yes, that's a G) of log files from one of my secondary servers. It's been running for just a few weeks. The path to the log files was C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install (thank goodness for WinDirStat).

Am I missing a configuration setting or something? Is there a reasonable way to keep these log files under control? I suppose I could create a script to remove them, but it seems like the Web Farm Framework shouldn't cause the server to crash after just a few weeks of running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I just needed to install Web Platform Installer 3.0. Apparently I had 2.0 installed and it didn't like that.

The line from the log file that clued me in was:

> Install return code for product 'Web
>   Farm Framework 2.0' is Failure (Web
>   Platform Installer 3.0 is a
>   pre-requisite for installing Web Farm
>   Framework 2.0.  Please install the Web
>   Plaform Installer from
>   http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx.
>   )

I've been watching the logs since I installed it and it doesn't look like I have any new log files since then.

Answer (score 1):

Is this continuing to be an issue?  From what I can tell this should only be installation logs, not running logs.  Sometimes these installers can have trouble and remain running, etc.  If you've removed the logs and the folder size stays the same you should be all set.

If not, review the logs and paste some of the lines you feel relevant back here.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was a problem with installation of WPI. It needed version 3 and I had version 2 on the server.